# T-SQL Stop after first record matches inline query calculation condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check if a merchant is near my long lat values or not. I dont need all those that are near, i just need to know whether atleast 1 is near or not.

Using the below query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  TOP 1
        Id, 
        ImagePath,
        Title,
        Latitude,
        Longitude,
        'Distance' = dbo.GetHaversineDistance(77.050888, 28.581181, Longitude, Latitude),
        [Address],
        City,
        PinCode,
        [State],
        Phone,
        DateCreated,
        DateLastUpdated,
        IsDeleted,
        MerchantCode
    FROM MerchantLocations 
    ORDER BY Distance

) AS Locations
WHERE Distance <= 50
```

Despite having Top 1, I know the Haversine calculation is done for all my records in the table, they are then sorted by distance, and then I pick the Top 1.

Is it possible to stop the table scan and the haversine calculation once atleast 1 record is less than 50? Is there a way to NOT do the haversine calculation for all records?

Comment: Of course the calculation for `Distance` needs to be done for every row, that's the column you're ordering by. You can't put the rows into order of `Distance` until you've calculated the value *for* `Distance`.

Comment: I don't see much room for improvement here, because you need to know the distance for each data point in order to return closest point (among all points within a distance of 50).

Comment: I *suspect* however, you could improve the performance of the query by converting the Multiline Scalar Function to an inline table-value function (or, if you *are* on 2019 an inline scalar function might be possible, but as it's been out for 2 days, I doubt you're using it).

Comment: Imagine if you were asked for the person with the highest **total** value of all their bank balance. You are given a list of people, and the values of their individual balances, but not a total value. Some people only have 1 account, but others 10's. Could you easily select the correct person without summing the values of their individual balances? No, you couldn't. SQL Server has to do exactly the same thing here; it has to work out the value of `Distance` first, and then it can put all the rows in the correct order and return the `TOP (1)`. `Distance` **must** be calculated first.

Comment: @Larnu I understand your point, but i am actually coming from view point of a iteration like construct where I could break out of my for or foreach loop, once I calculate distance(1 record at a time) and it turns out to be less than 50.

Comment: SQL isn't a programming language, it's a Query Language (as the name suggests). It doesn't iterate, it uses set based logic.

Comment: @Larnu the bank example would align with my problem if i was looking for the nearest/least-distance. I am just looking for a bool (Yes or No) whether a merchant is near me or not. Lets say there are 5 merchants near me. M1 to M5..in same order or proximity. M1 nearest M5 farthest but all 5 within 50KM. I dont take care to have M1 as my result. I am ok with M5 also... So calculating distance for a thousands of records doesnt make sense.

Comment: If you just want to "know" if there *is* a row, then why not use an `EXISTS` and drop the `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`? SQL Server *can* short circuit an `EXISTS` query. It can't, however, not calculate the value of an expression for **every** row when you've told it to put the rows in order of that value.

Comment: The Haversine distance function is expensive because of the square root calculation. If you're only looking for merchants within 50km of a given point you could short-list the records where Latitude is +/- 0.5 degree (approx. +/- 55.5km) and Longitude is +/- 0.5 degree (approx. +/- 55.25km at the equator, +/- 45.85km at the poles) and only compute the Haversine distance for the filtered results. It's still going to have to scan all the rows, though, to determine whether any given merchant is within range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect this formulation to return the "first" encountered row with a distance less than 50:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ml.*, v.distance
FROM MerchantLocations ml CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (dbo.GetHaversineDistance(77.050888, 28.581181, Longitude, Latitude))
     ) v(distance)
WHERE distance <= 50;
```

Using `ORDER BY` is going to require that all the rows are evaluated, so the distance needs to be calculated to for all rows.

If you are storing and processing geographic data, you might consider a spatial index.  This might speed up many of your queries; the place to start is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: No idea, never heard of it. :) Thanks @Gordon. This is indeed an optimum solution, if its doing what i am assuming its doing :) . And also, thanks for the suggestion on spatial index, would keep that in mind in a future enhancement